# Capacitive voltage divider question

Tags: voltage, capacitive, divider

I see a few discussions on this but cannot really find the "definitive" answer.

I am building an audio amp and have two modules, one requires 18-0-18V AC and the other 12-0V AC, the 12V device requires 500mA approx. I have an 18-0-18 120W 50Hz transformer so have no issue with the 18V supply, but want to avoid using another transformer for 12-0V AC.

I have looked at resistive dividers but at 3:2 ratio at 500mA, these will be more like a heater, estimated need 10W resistors.

Now capacitive appears an option with 80uF (40Ω) and 160uF (20Ω). I will breadboard this but two questions:

My calculations show this will deliver around 450mA, what type and rating of cap should I use? I presume polyester 150V, but need guidance.

Other question, the heat dissipation appears to be around 8-9W, like the pure resistive solution, its significant, what is the effect on the caps?

Never tried this before so any pointers will be helpful. If the idea is a non-starter and my limited electronics knowledge has led me to a dead end, please be kind!

Comment: It is very likely that your 12V AC signal will be turned into DC and then regulated to give a stable DC voltage, so you may not need to provide 12V AC afterall. You will need to know what is further down the "electronics chain" after the 12V AC input so that you can possibly tap-in a DC voltage directly, one that is derived from your single 18-0V AC. Do you have access to the schematic diagrams of these "modules" you mention you want to use to audio amplify ? further info may be required ...

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer something you did not ask.  You state that you have "two modules".  The description of the power requirements make it fairly likely that you are talking about a power amp with symmetric voltage rails and a preamp with internal DC offsets (typical for a discrete preamp).  The signal grounds of those are *not* independent.  In addition, power amp rails are fairly tolerant of ripple and may exhibit significant fluctuations under load that also affect their DC behavior.

There are transformers built explicitly for that kind of strong/weak load typical for amps.  Short of such a transformer, an extra small transformer is not the worst idea.  Otherwise it's an option to just pick off the rectified voltage from the positive supply rail of the power amp (which is about +24V) and stabilise your preamp voltage off that.  With a linear regulator, you'll be cranking out 12W of heat.  It seems saner to just get an extra 12V transformer here and be independent.

Capacitive dividers, in contrast, will cause you trouble without end.  Particularly because you will be combining them with a voltage source with an inductive inner resistance and possibly high intermittent load.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply, and yes it is a main amp and preamp. They can both run from +/-12V but with much reduced output from the main amp, I also dug around in the pre-amp circuit and with some component changes it can happily run from 18V, so thats what I will do not, also I don't have space for an addition transformer!. Cheers

Comment: @JohnEarley - Hi, Your comment suggests that you have received as much help as you need. So in order to mark the topic as solved, please consider ["accepting" this answer](/help/someone-answers) (i.e. click the "tick mark" next to that answer, to turn it green). Although accepting an answer isn't mandatory, it is *encouraged* as your question is then shown as having an accepted answer in various lists, it makes it clear that you aren't waiting for more answers, and we don't get nagged for it being a question without an accepted answer. Thanks!